# My bus hasn't left Salem for several hours, no ETA updated - It's hours behind schedule, What should I do?

Tags: usa, public-transport, greyhound

I'm waiting for my bus which was scheduled to pick up an hour ago at 1am.  I have been tracking it since 10pm, and its ETA hasn't changed and it shows that the bus is stopped in Salem, hours from where I am, and this has been the status so far. The time of its arrival in Salem changed from 10pm to 11:15pm. According to the tracker, its just sitting in Salem.

I don't want to leave in case it shows up, but I also don't want to remain at the bus stop for hours. There is one bus every 24 hours on this route. The call center doesn't open until 10am. The 48 hour rule dictates that I'll need to purchase another ticket if I don't board this bus, regardless of the reason. Several people are waiting here for the north-bound bus in the hope its driver will have answers.

Any help?

Comment: Possibly because the bus broke down in Salem, they got another bus, but didn't move the tracker to the new bus.  Are all the people standing around also people using the app, who came late because they saw the bus wasn't near? The bus may have come and gone on schedule.  The app is a cutesey toy, the schedule is what matters.

Comment: I hope that after 11 hours OP has gotten on the bus and to their destination. I think OP is referring to this tracking tool - https://bustracker.greyhound.com/ . I am posting this comment in case there is some feature of the tool or hidden setting that would help answer OPs question.

Comment: Please, don't forget to update this question. Did you get on a bus?

Comment: What was the final outcome of this?

Comment: Not that it necessarily matters, but https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=What+states+have+a+Salem%3F&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjusrSo0MbvAhX1FVkFHRffA2YQzmd6BAgWEAo&biw=1327&bih=853 points out there are 9 towns or cities in the United States named Salem; you might want to clarify which one

Comment: @Foon and I'll never understand _why_...

Comment: Why is this a *Hot Network Question*? Seems abandoned!

Comment: @BernhardDöbler, the system that select for that list are not bothered about that. And I see no reason to take it of.

Comment: @o0'. maybe the same reason the USA has no less than a 18 Londons, 23 Parises, 26 Berlins, for some reason none of these occur on Wikipedia's list, [but there are 27 Salems on that list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_U.S._place_names#Salem_(27))

Comment: We need to know, did you get on that bus? What happened in the end? :)

Comment: that's why I hate SE for allowing unregistered account to post questions/answers. Looks like 99% of them got abandoned without even the proper answer

Comment: @phuclv Also, this question was posted only yesterday, so there is still a chance that this person is still traveling/unpacking/sleeping/getting settled etc, and may not have given a StackExchange post their top priority. Give it a couple days. Even if it is determined to be abandoned doesn't make the questions or answers any less useful to others.

Comment: @PCLuddite there's a kind of "unregistered account" which you can click on the OP's profile or use the [sox addon](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) to see. You just need an email instead of an account to ask. [What does it mean when someone's an Unregistered User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68524/230282). In my experience most of them never went back after getting the answer, before even a proper answer is given

Comment: @phuclv I was not aware of that feature and stand corrected. I deleted my first comment as I'm inclined to agree with you that it would most likely attract standalone posts. I haven't given up hope this won't be revisited quite yet, but am certainly more skeptical now.

Comment: @phuclv please see our Meta post on this subject: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5060/why-allow-unregistered-users/5067#5067

Answer (score 35):

https://numberforliveperson.com/greyhound/

The page lists phone numbers, wait strategy and Twitter and Facebook contacts

> In order to speak to a live person in Greyhound customer service, you need to dial 1-877-943-3530. For contact with a live agent, you need to stay on the line.
> Greyhound Customer Service Options
> Greyhound Phone Customer Service
> For ticket, fare & travel info you need to dial 1-800-231-2222. Representatives are available 24/7.
> For lost or damaged baggage you need to dial 1-214-849-6246. Representatives are available Monday – Friday 5am – 11pm CT.
> For road rewards inquiries you need to dial 1-877-943-3530. Representatives are available 24/7.
> For problems with website or app you need to dial 1-800-268-9000. Representatives are available 24/7.
> To travel for business by Greyhound you need to dial 1-800-440-7712. Representatives are available Monday – Friday 6:30am – 8pm CT.

Answer (score 34):

Normally, you do not blindly believe a sat navigation sending you to that pond ahead at the end of the road. Similarly, tracking systems of public transportation have mostly supplemental value. From people who understand them more in depth I know that many scenarios of incorrect indication can happen:

- the vehicle broke and but it remains assigned (logged in) to the route by driver's mistake
- a spare vehicle is doing the route, but it is not equipped by tracking system so you do not see it coming
- the driver mistakenly signs their vehicle onto improper route
- the dispatcher mistakenly assigns incorrect vehicle for given route
- some other cases (related to various technical details)

This way, you can sometimes see hilarious things how a streetcar (a tram) is approaching your stop using a street without tracks - because a backup bus has been sent as a replacement and the data are de-facto correct. So take these trackers with a grain of salt.

Of course, in situations of true mistakes, the vehicle is improperly indicated also at the central dispatching, but this is not a big issue: If this comes into their attention, it can usually be fixed by checking with the driver directly, and rectifying the setup.

In whatever public transportation systems this happens and you need to reach out, you typically prefer contact numbers for **central dispatching** if listed publicly (some providers in my country provide them). If not, you pick something closely related, like a general customer line and they can contact the back office to obtain the proper information for you.

Comment: Loving the _The Office (US)_ reference to open!